# Issues running pyspark code via Spark.submit but not with Jupyter-notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I am facing an issue with my pyspark code. the purpose of the code is to decode hex values and write it into a field.
the code runs perfectly fine in jupyter environment. but when it is run as a spark.submit, it finishes fine, but the required field is nulls(in other words no decoding).

Is any one aware of an issue like that? where the code works perfectly in Jupyter notebook, but you do a spark.submit , then it wont work.

Any inputs appreciated.

Below is the code that works properly in Jupyternotebook. the code is iterating thru the rows and applying a function.

```
df = (df
  .rdd
  .map(lambda row: sql.Row(
          **row.asDict(),  
          dec_spec=split_spec(row))  
  )
  .toDF()
 )
```

Now when i run via spark.submit, it gets syntax error. please see below PLease see the caret sign at the comma after asDict

```
>      df=df.rdd.map(lambda row:sql.Row(**row.asDict(),dec_spec=split_spec(row))).toDF()
                                                      ^
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>     20/12/16 09:59:56 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: python version of jupyter, and of pyspark?

Comment: It is pyspark version

Comment: what is the value of PYSPARK_PYTHON variable

Comment: how do  u find that out? Do you think, it has anything to do with that. Wht i know, is there is no version difference between those as both jupyter notebook and spark.submit is done on the same cluster

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to different version of python that was running jupyter and spark.submit.

The configurations made it difficult to figure out initially.